# ¿Quien sabe como solucionar el comando cmake .. al intentar instalar la polybar en ParrotSecurity?

Tags: ubuntu, security

***He intentado instalar la polybar con los siguientes comandos, y aun no logro entender el porque NO funciona.***

```
cd /home/arch/Descargas/
git clone --recursive https://github.com/polybar/polybar
cd polybar/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

***y cuando ejecuto el comando cmake .. me sale el siguiente error***

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/arch/Descargas/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/arch/Descargas/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué error te devuelve antes de ese mensaje?

```
>> cmake ..
-- No build type specified; using Release
-- Couldn't locate ccache, disabling ccache...
-- Using supported compiler GNU-10.2.1
-- Checking for module 'libuv'
--   No package 'libuv' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/common/utils.cmake:45 (pkg_check_modules)
  cmake/modules/FindLibUV.cmake:9 (find_package_impl)
  cmake/libpoly.cmake:51 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/***/Descargas/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/***/Descargas/polybar/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

En mi caso era al comprobar la libreria libuv, que solucioné instalando la versión *libuv1-dev*

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score -2):

tuve el mismo error, con la informacion del comentario de arriba, pude solucionar con

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libuv1-dev
```

Comment: Bienvenido. El de *arriba* no es un comentario, es una respuesta. Y *arriba* es subjetivo ya que las respuestas se pueden ordenar. Tu publicación es un comentario en la zona de respuestas. Te invito a editarla si tienes algo que aportar sino eliminarla. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios de verdad. Por favor aprende a usar el sitio. No es un foro y tiene su propio funcionamiento. Puedes encontrar más información en [tour], [ask], [answer] y [help]. Si tienes dudas sobre el sitio puedes dejarlas en [meta] o el [chat].